# Solving $n! + 3n = k^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Let $n$ and $k$ be integers.

Need to solve $n! + 3n = k^2$, where $n!$ denotes $n$ factorial.

I do not have any ideas about this equation, except I suppose the only $6$ roots are $(0,1), (0, -1), (1, 2), (1, -2), (4, 6),$ and $(4, -6)$

Can anybody prove that these are the only roots?

Answer (score 5):

Just a partial answer for now.

We can write our equation as:
$$n\cdot\left((n-1)!+3\right)=k^2,$$
so, assuming that there is a prime $p$ such that $p\mid n$ and $\nu_p(n)\equiv{1}\pmod{2}$, then $p$ must divide $(n-1)!+3$. This can happen only if $p=3$. So we have only two chances: $n$ is a square or $3,27,243,\ldots$ times a square. The problems now boils down to finding the integers $m$ for which
$$ m! + 3 = k^2\quad\text{or}\quad m!+3=3k^2. $$
The first case cannot occur if $m\geq 4$, since in such a case $m!+3\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ cannot be a square. If $m\geq 6$, the second case is equivalent to:
$$2\cdot 4\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot m = (k-1)(k+1),$$
or (since $k$ must be odd) to:
$$2\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot m = k(k+1).$$

Comment: The second case feels about as intractable as Brocard's problem (not withstanding Mochizuki's proposed proof of ABC).

Comment: @ErickWong: I have the same feeling, but maybe we can prove that $12k(k+1)$ does not represent any factorial apart from $4!$ with some clever trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just a list; I put in a factoring command with a bound, so it is fast, here I said investigate prime factors of $n! + 3 n$ only up to 10,000. As you can see, the prime factorization of $n$ influences the prime factors of $n! + 3 n.$ As others have said, you can also use conditions $\bmod 4$ without knowing the full factorization of anything. Note how, for $n \geq 7,$ if $n$ is not divisible by $3$ then "OUTCOME" is divisible by $3$ but not $9,$ so cannot be a square. Oh, for the big number, I had it write cdot in case I wanted to convert to Latex later. Annoying.

Alright, read through a printout, it just support's Jack's idea that the number is ruled out by either $3$ or by a prime dividing $n$ unless $n = 3 k^2.$

```
1 =  1   OUTCOME    = 2^2
2 = 2  OUTCOME    = 2^3
3 = 3  OUTCOME    = 3  cdot 5
4 = 2^2  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3^2
5 = 5  OUTCOME    = 3^3  cdot 5
6 = 2 * 3  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^2  cdot 41
7 = 7  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 7  cdot 241
8 = 2^3  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3 cdot 41^2
9 = 3^2  OUTCOME    = 3^3  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
10 = 2 * 5  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 5 cdot 73  cdot 1657
11 = 11  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 11 cdot 17  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
12 = 2^2 * 3  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3^2  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
13 = 13  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 13 cdot 103  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
14 = 2 * 7  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 7 cdot 19 cdot 67 cdot 1021  cdot 1597
15 = 3 * 5  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 5 cdot 43  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
16 = 2^4  OUTCOME    = 2^4 cdot 3 cdot 19 cdot 89  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
17 = 17  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 17 cdot 821 cdot 3089  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
18 = 2 * 3^2  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^3  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
19 = 19  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 19 cdot 47 cdot 89  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
20 = 2^2 * 5  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 5 cdot 37 cdot 467  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
21 = 3 * 7  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 7 cdot 29  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
22 = 2 * 11  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 11  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
23 = 23  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 23 cdot 283  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
24 = 2^3 * 3  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3^2  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
25 = 5^2  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 5^2  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
26 = 2 * 13  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 13  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
27 = 3^3  OUTCOME    = 3^4 cdot 37  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
28 = 2^2 * 7  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 7 cdot 1873  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
29 = 29  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 29 cdot 2011  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
30 = 2 * 3 * 5  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^2 cdot 5 cdot 331 cdot 2939  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
31 = 31  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 31  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
32 = 2^5  OUTCOME    = 2^5 cdot 3 cdot 73 cdot 311 cdot 5197  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
33 = 3 * 11  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 11 cdot 157 cdot 317  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
34 = 2 * 17  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 17  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
35 = 5 * 7  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 5 cdot 7 cdot 43  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
36 = 2^2 * 3^2  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3^3 cdot 251  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
37 = 37  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 37  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
38 = 2 * 19  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 19 cdot 163  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
39 = 3 * 13  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 13  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
40 = 2^3 * 5  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3 cdot 5  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
41 = 41  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 41 cdot 109 cdot 1483  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
42 = 2 * 3 * 7  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^2 cdot 7  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
43 = 43  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 43  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
44 = 2^2 * 11  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 11  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
45 = 3^2 * 5  OUTCOME    = 3^3 cdot 5 cdot 2293  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
46 = 2 * 23  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 23 cdot 127  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
47 = 47  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 47 cdot 97 cdot 967  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
48 = 2^4 * 3  OUTCOME    = 2^4 cdot 3^2 cdot 89 cdot 137  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
49 = 7^2  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 7^2  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
50 = 2 * 5^2  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 5^2 cdot 149  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
51 = 3 * 17  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 17 cdot 131  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
52 = 2^2 * 13  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 13 cdot 4219  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
53 = 53  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 53 cdot 347 cdot 1489 cdot 7253  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
54 = 2 * 3^3  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^4 cdot 4339  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
55 = 5 * 11  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 5 cdot 11  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
56 = 2^3 * 7  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3 cdot 7 cdot 593  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
57 = 3 * 19  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 19 cdot 71 cdot 223  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
58 = 2 * 29  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 29  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
59 = 59  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 59  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
60 = 2^2 * 3 * 5  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3^2 cdot 5 cdot 1039  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
61 = 61  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 61 cdot 211  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
62 = 2 * 31  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 31  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
63 = 3^2 * 7  OUTCOME    = 3^3 cdot 7 cdot 1787  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
64 = 2^6  OUTCOME    = 2^6 cdot 3  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
65 = 5 * 13  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 5 cdot 13  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
66 = 2 * 3 * 11  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^2 cdot 11  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
67 = 67  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 67 cdot 71  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
68 = 2^2 * 17  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 17 cdot 8753  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
69 = 3 * 23  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 23 cdot 733  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
70 = 2 * 5 * 7  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 5 cdot 7  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
71 = 71  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 71 cdot 953  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
72 = 2^3 * 3^2  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3^3 cdot 1601  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
73 = 73  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 73  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
74 = 2 * 37  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 37  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
75 = 3 * 5^2  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 5^2 cdot 199 cdot 211 cdot 373  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
76 = 2^2 * 19  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 19  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
77 = 7 * 11  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 7 cdot 11  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
78 = 2 * 3 * 13  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^2 cdot 13  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
79 = 79  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 79 cdot 113  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
80 = 2^4 * 5  OUTCOME    = 2^4 cdot 3 cdot 5 cdot 191 cdot 4583  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
81 = 3^4  OUTCOME    = 3^5  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
82 = 2 * 41  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 41 cdot 139  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
83 = 83  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 83  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
84 = 2^2 * 3 * 7  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3^2 cdot 7  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
85 = 5 * 17  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 5 cdot 17  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
86 = 2 * 43  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 43  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
87 = 3 * 29  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 29  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
88 = 2^3 * 11  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3 cdot 11 cdot 211 cdot 4639  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
89 = 89  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 89 cdot 97  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
90 = 2 * 3^2 * 5  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^3 cdot 5 cdot 1373  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
91 = 7 * 13  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 7 cdot 13 cdot 1571  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
92 = 2^2 * 23  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 23  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
93 = 3 * 31  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 31  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
94 = 2 * 47  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 47  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
95 = 5 * 19  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 5 cdot 19  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
96 = 2^5 * 3  OUTCOME    = 2^5 cdot 3^2 cdot 179  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
97 = 97  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 97  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
98 = 2 * 7^2  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 7^2  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
99 = 3^2 * 11  OUTCOME    = 3^3 cdot 11  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
100 = 2^2 * 5^2  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 5^2  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
101 = 101  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 101 cdot 1031 cdot 1277 cdot 2999  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
102 = 2 * 3 * 17  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^2 cdot 17 cdot 7933  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
103 = 103  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 103  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
104 = 2^3 * 13  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3 cdot 13  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
105 = 3 * 5 * 7  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 5 cdot 7 cdot 3677  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
106 = 2 * 53  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 53 cdot 5569  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
107 = 107  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 107 cdot 2393  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
108 = 2^2 * 3^3  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3^4 cdot 829  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
109 = 109  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 109 cdot 173 cdot 2287  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
110 = 2 * 5 * 11  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 5 cdot 11  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
111 = 3 * 37  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 37  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
112 = 2^4 * 7  OUTCOME    = 2^4 cdot 3 cdot 7 cdot 173  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
113 = 113  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 113  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
114 = 2 * 3 * 19  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^2 cdot 19  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
115 = 5 * 23  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 5 cdot 23  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
116 = 2^2 * 29  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 29 cdot 1051 cdot 3617  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
117 = 3^2 * 13  OUTCOME    = 3^3 cdot 13 cdot 1753  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
118 = 2 * 59  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 59  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
119 = 7 * 17  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 7 cdot 17 cdot 1439  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
120 = 2^3 * 3 * 5  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3^2 cdot 5 cdot 149 cdot 4049  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
121 = 11^2  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 11^2 cdot 127  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
122 = 2 * 61  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 61  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
123 = 3 * 41  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 41 cdot 5179  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
124 = 2^2 * 31  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 31 cdot 857 cdot 1789  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
125 = 5^3  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 5^3  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
126 = 2 * 3^2 * 7  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^3 cdot 7 cdot 997 cdot 2243  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
127 = 127  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 127 cdot 1187 cdot 2153  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
128 = 2^7  OUTCOME    = 2^7 cdot 3 cdot 569  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
129 = 3 * 43  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 43  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
130 = 2 * 5 * 13  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 5 cdot 13  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
131 = 131  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 131 cdot 191  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
132 = 2^2 * 3 * 11  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3^2 cdot 11  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
133 = 7 * 19  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 7 cdot 19 cdot 743  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
134 = 2 * 67  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 67 cdot 373 cdot 577  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
135 = 3^3 * 5  OUTCOME    = 3^4 cdot 5  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
136 = 2^3 * 17  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3 cdot 17 cdot 1889  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
137 = 137  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 137 cdot 7907  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
138 = 2 * 3 * 23  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^2 cdot 23  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
139 = 139  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 139 cdot 6133  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
140 = 2^2 * 5 * 7  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 5 cdot 7  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
141 = 3 * 47  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 47  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
142 = 2 * 71  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 71  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
143 = 11 * 13  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 11 cdot 13  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
144 = 2^4 * 3^2  OUTCOME    = 2^4 cdot 3^3  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
145 = 5 * 29  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 5 cdot 29  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
146 = 2 * 73  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 73 cdot 2659  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
147 = 3 * 7^2  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 7^2 cdot 179  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
148 = 2^2 * 37  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 37 cdot 211 cdot 271 cdot 2677  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
149 = 149  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 149  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
150 = 2 * 3 * 5^2  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^2 cdot 5^2  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
151 = 151  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 151  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
152 = 2^3 * 19  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3 cdot 19 cdot 1213  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
153 = 3^2 * 17  OUTCOME    = 3^3 cdot 17 cdot 1289  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
154 = 2 * 7 * 11  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 7 cdot 11 cdot 827 cdot 3463  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
155 = 5 * 31  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 5 cdot 31  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
156 = 2^2 * 3 * 13  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3^2 cdot 13  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
157 = 157  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 157 cdot 379  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
158 = 2 * 79  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 79 cdot 6037  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
159 = 3 * 53  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 53 cdot 1733 cdot 5407  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
160 = 2^5 * 5  OUTCOME    = 2^5 cdot 3 cdot 5 cdot 4003  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
161 = 7 * 23  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 7 cdot 23  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
162 = 2 * 3^4  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^5 cdot 331  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
163 = 163  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 163  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
164 = 2^2 * 41  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 41 cdot 271  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
165 = 3 * 5 * 11  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 5 cdot 11  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
166 = 2 * 83  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 83 cdot 239  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
167 = 167  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 167  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
168 = 2^3 * 3 * 7  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3^2 cdot 7  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
169 = 13^2  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 13^2 cdot 373 cdot 439 cdot 1489 cdot 4799  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
170 = 2 * 5 * 17  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 5 cdot 17  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
171 = 3^2 * 19  OUTCOME    = 3^3 cdot 19 cdot 317  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
172 = 2^2 * 43  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 43  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
173 = 173  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 173  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
174 = 2 * 3 * 29  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^2 cdot 29 cdot 883 cdot 3539  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
175 = 5^2 * 7  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 5^2 cdot 7 cdot 211  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
176 = 2^4 * 11  OUTCOME    = 2^4 cdot 3 cdot 11 cdot 6899  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
177 = 3 * 59  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 59  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
178 = 2 * 89  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 89  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
179 = 179  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 179 cdot 239 cdot 3593  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
180 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3^3 cdot 5  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
181 = 181  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 181 cdot 653  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
182 = 2 * 7 * 13  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 7 cdot 13 cdot 5581  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
183 = 3 * 61  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 61 cdot 337 cdot 5749  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
184 = 2^3 * 23  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3 cdot 23  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
185 = 5 * 37  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 5 cdot 37 cdot 571  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
186 = 2 * 3 * 31  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^2 cdot 31 cdot 1901  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
187 = 11 * 17  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 11 cdot 17  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
188 = 2^2 * 47  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 47  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
189 = 3^3 * 7  OUTCOME    = 3^4 cdot 7 cdot 3089  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
190 = 2 * 5 * 19  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 5 cdot 19  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
191 = 191  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 191  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
192 = 2^6 * 3  OUTCOME    = 2^6 cdot 3^2 cdot 4973  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
193 = 193  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 193  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
194 = 2 * 97  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3 cdot 97 cdot 839  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
195 = 3 * 5 * 13  OUTCOME    = 3^2 cdot 5 cdot 13  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
196 = 2^2 * 7^2  OUTCOME    = 2^2 cdot 3 cdot 7^2 cdot 947  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
197 = 197  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 197 cdot 421  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
198 = 2 * 3^2 * 11  OUTCOME    = 2 cdot 3^3 cdot 11 cdot 5653  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
199 = 199  OUTCOME    = 3 cdot 199 cdot 761 cdot 1259  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
200 = 2^3 * 5^2  OUTCOME    = 2^3 cdot 3 cdot 5^2 cdot 433  cdot  mbox{BIG} 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

---